# Formatting code "%s\n" is being read by MATLAB as a comment

Tags: string, matlab, formatting, comments, format

I want to write a string to a file and I'm using this code:

```
fprintf(fileID, %s\n, stringToWrite);
```

The problem is that from the `'%'` sign onward the line is being read as a comment, because `'%'` is the sign you use to start a comment in MATLAB.

Any idea on what I should do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Add some quotes:

```
fprintf(fileID, '%s\n', stringToWrite);
```